# playing sound effects in blender game engine depending on the speed of my car

Tags: audio

I'm making a car racing game and got everything pretty much done except for the sounds. i want to have it where when I accelerate or move pretty much I start with a certain soundtrack, and as I reach a certain speed I would move to the next track etc.... any ideas because I've tried it so many time but never worked.i would like to do this I code too.